# Angular 6: Prevent default beforeunload confirmation popup

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to restrict user to reload browser in a Angular 6 application. With the following code it shows a default confirmation popup but I want to show my own.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 doBeforeUnload($event) {
 return false;
}
```

If I remove "return false", event fires without default confirmation popup but doesn't stop refresh. Is there any way to stop reload without that popup?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `CanDeactivate` guard to deciding if a route can be deactivated,

```
CanDeactivate guard (ask permission to discard unsaved changes)
```

It is specified in https://angular.io/guide/router

From the current approach you cannot stop/override the default browser's confirmation box.

Comment: useful.. but seems to handle route navigations only and not if user hits browser tab refresh or F5. Nevertheless, give some direction